# Left outer join wrong result in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am working with MySQL joins. I have two tables in which I need a join. First table contains all the real estate properties and second table contains the users who add favorite to that property. Now I want to show all the property with the favorite icon for the user who login. I write the below query in  MySQL. But this query returns me all the record.

```
SELECT a. * , b.property_id AS fav, b.user_id
FROM `property_for_sale` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cpo_favourite_property` b ON a.id = b.property_id
WHERE a.property_type = 'Commercial'
UNION
SELECT a. * , b.property_id AS fav, b.user_id
FROM `property_for_rent` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cpo_favourite_property` b ON a.id = b.property_id
WHERE a.property_type = 'Commercial'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

There is one more problem with this. This query return me duplicate property if more than one user add the same property in favorite

Here is the final output I am getting from api when I use this query

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "user": [
        {
            "id": "1266",
            "date": "2016-01-25",
            "date_25_days": "2016-02-19",
            "date_30_days": "2016-02-24",
            "time": "04:47:40 PM",
            "user_name": "anil123", 
            "fileupload": "186_39151.jpg",
            "image2": "Null",
            "image3": "Null",
            "image4": "Null",
            "description": "gg",
            "fav": "1266",
            "user_id": "19"
        },
        {
            "id": "1266",
            "date": "2016-01-25",
            "date_25_days": "2016-02-19",
            "date_30_days": "2016-02-24",
            "time": "04:47:40 PM",
            "user_name": "anil123", 
            "fileupload": "186_39151.jpg",
            "image2": "Null",
            "image3": "Null",
            "image4": "Null",
            "description": "gg",
            "fav": "1266",
            "user_id": "480"
        },
        {
            "id": "1144",
            "date": "2015-12-07",
            "date_25_days": "2016-01-01",
            "date_30_days": "2016-01-06",
            "time": "05:45:30 PM",
            "user_name": "Realtyup Estate Agency", 
            "fileupload": "464_IMG-20140812-WA0063.jpg",
            "image2": "821_IMG-20140812-WA0064.jpg",
            "image3": "Null",
            "image4": "Null",
            "description": "Commercial showroom at Mansa Devi Complex Sector 4 Panchkula.Ground/basement/first/second fully constructed floors.Ample parking.Corner three side open.Well suited for any kind of business establishment",
            "fav": null,
            "user_id": null
        },
        {
            "id": "625",
            "date": "2016-02-01",
            "date_25_days": "2016-02-25",
            "date_30_days": "2016-03-01",
            "time": "02:25:40 AM",
            "user_name": "", 
            "fileupload": "Null",
            "image2": "Null",
            "image3": "Null",
            "image4": "Null",
            "description": "VjD7Gu http://www.FyLitCl7Pf7kjQdDUOLQOuaxTXbj5iNG.com",
            "fav": null,
            "user_id": null
        },
        {
            "id": "624",
            "date": "2016-01-31",
            "date_25_days": "2016-02-25",
            "date_30_days": "2016-03-01",
            "time": "05:44:10 PM",
            "user_name": "", 
            "fileupload": "Null",
            "image2": "Null",
            "image3": "Null",
            "image4": "Null",
            "description": "DIMgVX http://www.FyLitCl7Pf7kjQdDUOLQOuaxTXbj5iNG.com",
            "fav": null,
            "user_id": null
        },
        {
            "id": "623",
            "date": "2016-01-31",
            "date_25_days": "2016-02-25",
            "date_30_days": "2016-03-01",
            "time": "12:59:54 PM",
            "user_name": "", 
            "fileupload": "Null",
            "image2": "Null",
            "image3": "Null",
            "image4": "Null",
            "description": "2lx6j8 http://www.FyLitCl7Pf7kjQdDUOLQOuaxTXbj5iNG.com",
            "fav": null,
            "user_id": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you show sample data in tables/schema?

Comment: A LEFT OUTER join will return *all records* from the left table (only restricted by the WHERE clause) - property_for_sale and property_for_rent, in this case. Should it be an INNER join instead?

Comment: @Stidgeon Please check I add the result

Comment: @user2864740 I want to show all the records if any user add any property to favorite then it should change icon that's why I use left outer join. Inner join will return only that records which added in favorite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing restriction on currently logged user. Add it to the `ON` clause (`:currentUserId` placeholder):

```
SELECT a. * , b.property_id AS fav, b.user_id
FROM `property_for_sale` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cpo_favourite_property` b ON a.id = b.property_id AND b.user_id = :currentUserId
WHERE a.property_type = 'Commercial'
UNION
SELECT a. * , b.property_id AS fav, b.user_id
FROM `property_for_rent` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cpo_favourite_property` b ON a.id = b.property_id AND b.user_id = :currentUserId
WHERE a.property_type = 'Commercial'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show both users then use below query-

```
SELECT a. * , b.property_id AS fav, group_concat(b.user_id)
FROM `property_for_sale` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cpo_favourite_property` b ON a.id = b.property_id
WHERE a.property_type = 'Commercial'
group by a.id
UNION
SELECT a. * , b.property_id AS fav, group_concat(b.user_id)
FROM `property_for_rent` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cpo_favourite_property` b ON a.id = b.property_id
WHERE a.property_type = 'Commercial'
group by a.id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Note: If you don't want to show multiple comma seperated users then don't use group_concat function then your query will just give you first user.